# MySQL: selecting rows by two of three primary keys

Tags: mysql, select, primary-key

I am searching for exactly the opposite of what Jonathan was searching in this example:

[How to select multiple rows by multi-column primary key in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230560/how-to-select-multiple-rows-by-multi-column-primary-key-in-mysql)

Having 3 columns as a primary key (the 3rd is a date), I want to select all of them without the most recent one. And if there is no second entry for a combination of the first two primary values, I don't want to select it at all. Think of it as a kind of versioning. The table-structure contains more columns than those three and i want to select the whole rows.

Looks something like that:

```
{ID1 | ID2 | DATE} | more columns ...
```

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (first and second primary value are the same and exist more than once) AND NOT MAX(date)
```

:D

I want to output the data of all previous versions of the row, not including the most recent one.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down the problem into steps:

Pseudo logic:

- Get a data set with the records we want to exclude
- now exclude that data set from the entire set

Step 1: Get a dataset of only those records having a max data for ID1, ID2

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, Max(date) date 
           FROM Table 
           GROUP BY ID1, ID2
```

Step 2: Now use that data set to identify/eliminate the records you don't want.. a not exists is likely the fastest.

Faster...

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE A
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 
 FROM (SELECT ID1, ID2, Max(date) date 
       FROM Table 
       GROUP BY ID1, ID2) B
 WHERE A.ID1 = B.ID1 
   and A.ID2 = B.ID2
   and A.Date = B.Date)
```

or as a self outer join on a subset, slower but gives you access to additional details on subset if needed.  (not much use in this example but could be useful in other circumstances)

The left join to the data set shows those that match on the max date, so all other records would be null, which is the data set you're after...

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID1, ID2, Max(date) date 
           FROM Table 
           GROUP BY ID1, ID2) B
  on A.ID1 = B.ID1 
 and A.ID2 = B.ID2
 and A.Date = B.Date
WHERE B.ID1 is null
```

Comment: due to not being able to edit my own comment yet, here's a second one: Wow, that was fast! Well explained and working! :) the first one gives me exactly what i was searching for, the second one with the left join adds columns with NULL to my data set, which could interfer with the real data, couldn't it? you missed a closing -> ( <- in your first solution at the very end :)

Comment: 2nd one we could just use A.* instead of * and null columns go away. and I added in the missing )  The null columns wouldn't interfere, but they would always be null based on the the join criteria and where clause. so pointless which is why I added the A.*.  Keep in mind I don't have your data set so we don't get the chance to "test" unless we mockup data.